# Can I use a Global Entry Kiosk on a new passport?

Tags: usa, uk-citizens, global-entry

I am a UK Citizen with a B1/B2 Visa and a Global Entry Member and have just renewed my passport. I have the original passport with a corner cut off, which I understand I will need to bring with me to the US as it still contains my valid visa.

I have registered the details of my new passport using the TTP Portal: https://ttp.cbp.dhs.gov/ and also entered the details of this passport into the Advance Passenger Information (API) of my upcoming booking.

Will I be able to use the Global Entry Kiosk when I land, or should I proceed through the 'Visitors' lane to be interviewed by a CBP Officer as I would if I were entering the US on an ESTA and new passport for the first time?

Comment: I don't need an esta (I'm Canadian) but I went into the US with a new passport using the Global Entry kiosks after telling them about the new passport online, and had no issues. FWIW.

Comment: ESTA and the visa waiver program are not relevant to you because you have a visa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a Global Entry member, received a new passport, entered it into the portal online before my trip, and was able to use the kiosks without any problems. I'm a US Citizen, though I know of no reason why it should be different for a foreign national, unless you've done something like changed your name.

I can't see why you shouldn't try using the kiosk, since you're a member and you paid for it. At worst, it comes up with the "X" on your slip because your visa is in a different passport, and you have to speak to someone to get it resolved. The line for people with Global Entry issues is usually much shorter than the general visitor line though.

Comment: +1, had exactly the same experience with a new passport. Before (a couple years ago) you were required to visit Global Entry enrollment center after getting a new passport so they'd put a sticker into it. But now this is obsolete.

Comment: It works the same for foreign citizens (I'm a non-resident Canadian citizen with NEXUS membership, which confers Global Entry benefits).  It's necessary to update the passport details on DHS's website first, but having done this, it will work.

Comment: I've accepted this as I entered with no issues on the new passport today. The machine accepted the passport and picked up my visa type as it did with the old passport. Thanks!